# CSS selector: applying :focus on navbar

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, less

Following with ADA-compliant, I need to make the navbar expand either when the user's mouse is over at the navbar (using :hover) or if the user's mouse is focused on one of the items in the navbar.

Although I was able to figure it the first part, I am having trouble implementing the second requirement.

Here's a code snippet to demonstrate my current implementation:

https://codepen.io/neotriz/pen/MoBMvz?editors=1100

**CSS:**

```
.nav-template {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    transition: width 0.3s linear;
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: black;
    width: 70px;
    &:hover{
        width: 150px;
    }

    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;

        li {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            cursor: pointer;
            &:hover {
                background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
            }
            a {
                color: white;
                height: 40px;
                margin-left: 12px;
                margin-right: 35px;
                padding-bottom: 10px;
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like if I apply &:focus where &:hover is, it doesn't work because it is thinking the entire navbar needs to be selected in order to expand it, as suppose to focusing on each individual items.

Is my current implementation needs some reworking?

Comment: `:focus` css only works on inputs (such as buttons/textboxes), can't work on a div unfortunately

Comment: I see. Any advice on how meet the second requirement without using `:focus` then?

Comment: What if you add an :active state to your .nav-template class, setting it to the same width as your :hover state?

Comment: @HenryVisotski, can you provide a sample code if possible?

Comment: you can make any element focusable with the `tabindex` attribute. e.g `<div tabindex="0"></div>` would make the div able to take the `:focus` psuedoclass

Comment: .nav-template {
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 transition: width 0.3s linear;
 display: flex;
 overflow: hidden;
 background: black;
 width: 70px;
 &:hover{
  width: 150px;
 }
   &:active{
  width: 150px;
  }

Comment: @HenryVisotski, thanks for responding, but this doesnt seem to solve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Some thing Like this

HTML

```
<div tabindex="1" class="nav-template">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

LESS

```
.nav-template {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: black;
    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    transition: width 0.3s linear;
        li {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            cursor: pointer;
            a {
                color: white;
                height: 40px;
                margin-left: 12px;
                margin-right: 35px;
                padding-bottom: 10px;
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                text-decoration: none;
                width:70px;
                transition:all ease 0.5s;
        &:focus,&:hover {
                width: 100px;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
            }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

CSS

```
.nav-template {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: black;
}
.nav-template ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transition: width 0.3s linear;
}
.nav-template ul li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.nav-template ul li a {
  color: white;
  height: 40px;
  margin-left: 12px;
  margin-right: 35px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  width:70px;
  transition:all ease 0.5s;
}
.nav-template ul li a:focus,
.nav-template ul li a:hover {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
}
```

use :focus on the anchor tag increase its width, :focus works on div but the problem here is when you are focusing it is directly focused on the anchor tag but not on the div or the li or ul

add these rules for transition

```
.nav-template ul li a{
width:70px;
transition:all ease 0.5s;
}
```

[Link For reference](https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/fy93xk50/8/)

give this a try

hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks for the response! This seems a good start. I am having trouble where to put the `transition` attribute for this example though

Comment: @Alejandro just updated the code and also the fiddle give this a try. hope this helps...